# how to style material UI popper

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to modify the padding styling for the div with the 'css-ypiqx9-MuiDialogContent-root' class highlighted in the image below:

[image]

Here is what I tried so far, but the styles haven't been applied:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    // Dropdown container
    paper: {
      borderRadius: 0,
      boxShadow: 'none',
      border: '1px solid lightgray',
      borderBottomLeftRadius: 20,
      borderBottomRightRadius: 20,
      top: -1,
      margin: 0,
      position: open ? 'relative' : 'absolute',
      width: '100%',
    },

    root: {
      '& .MuiAutocomplete-tag': {
        margin: '0 3px',
      },
      '& .MuiDialogContent-root': {
        paddingBottom: '2px !important',
      },
    },
    popperDisablePortal: {
      position: 'relative',
    },
    groupLabel: {
      fontWeight: 600,
      textTransform: 'uppercase',
    },
    option: {
      // paddingLeft: '16px !important',
      height: 48,
    },
    listbox: {
      maxHeight: 355,
    },
    input: 
  })

  const classes = useStyles()

return (
      <Autocomplete
        PopperComponent={props => <Paper {...props} />}
        filterOptions={filterOptions}
        isOptionEqualToValue={(o: any, value: any) =>
          selectedOptions.find((op: any) => value.type === o.type && value.id === o.id)
        }
        onChange={(event: any, value: any) => handleAddUserGroup(value)}
        ListboxProps={{ id: 'list', role: 'list-box' }}
        ListboxComponent={ListboxComponent}
        disableListWrap
        disablePortal
        disableCloseOnSelect
        multiple
        classes={{ ...classes }}
```

How can I style the MUI popper component?